# Dynamically created hidden inputs by JavaScript do not come to parameterbag

Tags: javascript, html, symfony

I create some hidden inputs dynamically by JavaScript. But they are not appearing in the parameterbag of the request when the form is submitted. I've used this same method in one of my previous twigs and it works quiet fine. I can't figure out what causes the error in this case. Parameterbag only contains the values of inputs coming from the form admin.

```
{% extends('base.html.twig') %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <h3>Vehicle Classes</h3>
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="registeredVehicleClasses" name="vehicleClasses[]">
                {% if( vehicleClasses|length >0) %}
                    {% set i=1 %}
                    {% for vehicleClass in vehicleClasses %}
                        <option>{{ vehicleClass.className }}        |        {{ vehicleClass.toll }}</option>
                        <script>
                            var input = document.createElement("input");
                            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

                            input.setAttribute("name", "vehicleClasses["+"{{ i }}" +"]");
                            input.setAttribute("id", "vehicleClasses["+"{{ i }}" +"]");

                            input.setAttribute("value", "{{ vehicleClass.className  }}" + "        |        " + "{{ vehicleClass.toll }}");
                            document.getElementById('registeredVehicleClasses').appendChild(input);
                        </script>
                        {%  set i = i+1 %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <h3>Highways</h3>
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="registeredHighways" name="highways[]">
                {% if( highways|length >0) %}
                    {% set i=1 %}
                    {% for highway in highways %}
                        <option>{{ highway.name }}        |        {{ highway.codeName }}</option>
                        <script>
                            var input = document.createElement("input");

                            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

                            input.setAttribute("name", "highways["+"{{ i }}" +"]");
                            input.setAttribute("id", "highways["+"{{ i }}" +"]");

                            input.setAttribute("value", "{{ highway.name }}        |        {{ highway.codeName }}");
                            document.getElementById('registeredHighways').appendChild(input);
                        </script>
                        {%  set i = i+1 %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <h3>Highway Interchanges</h3>
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="registeredHighwayExtensions" name="highwayExtensions[]">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 0.2cm;"></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="float: right;">
            <button type="button" id="removeVehicleClass" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="float: right;">
            <button type="button" id="removeHighway" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="float: right;">
            <button type="button" id="removeHighwayExtension" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{ form_start(form) }}

    <div id="admin">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.className) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.className) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.highwayName) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.highwayName) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.highwayExtensionName) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.highwayExtensionName) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.toll) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.toll) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.highwayCodeName) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.highwayCodeName) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.highwayExtensionCodeName) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.highwayExtensionCodeName) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <button type="button" id="addVehicleClass" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <button type="button" id="addHighway" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.sequenceNo) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.sequenceNo) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    {{ form_errors(form.macAddress) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.macAddress) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <button type="button" id="addHighwayExtension" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">{{ form_widget(form.save) }}</div>
    <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
</div>

{{ form_row(form._token) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

</form>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script>
    const addVehicleClassButton = document.getElementById('addVehicleClass');
    const className = document.getElementById('admin_className');
    const toll = document.getElementById('admin_toll');
    const addedVehicleClasses = document.getElementById('registeredVehicleClasses');
    const removeVehicleClassButton = document.getElementById('removeVehicleClass');
    addVehicleClassButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = className.value + "        |        " + toll.value ;
        opt.innerHTML = className.value + "        |        " + toll.value;
        var existingOptions = addedVehicleClasses.options;
        var isExist = false;

        for(var i=0;i<existingOptions.length;i++){
            if(existingOptions[i].value == opt.value){
                isExist = true;
            }
        }


        if(isExist == false){
            addedVehicleClasses.appendChild(opt);

            var input = document.createElement("input");

            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

            input.setAttribute("name", "vehicleClasses["+addedVehicleClasses.length +"]");
            input.setAttribute("id", "vehicleClasses["+addedVehicleClasses.length +"]");

            input.setAttribute("value", className.value + "        |        " + toll.value);
            addedVehicleClasses.appendChild(input);
        }


    });
    removeVehicleClassButton.addEventListener("click",function () {
        try{
            var options = addedVehicleClasses.getElementsByTagName('OPTION');
            document.getElementById( "vehicleClasses["+(addedVehicleClasses.selectedIndex+1)+"]").remove();
            addedVehicleClasses.removeChild(options[addedVehicleClasses.selectedIndex]);
        }catch (e) {

        }
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ form_start(form) }}` is after the hidden form tags. Any form elements before this function will not be included in the request.

You should move `form_start` up in your HTML so that it encloses all form elements you want to be submitted.